# Explode return array but when using index to get value from that array it returns arrays bracket with it

Tags: laravel

Explode return array but when using index to get value from that array it returns arrays bracket with it. When I use array[0] it returns the value but with starting bracket "[" and when array[1] it returns the value with ending bracket "]"

```
 $files = $request->images;
 $str_arr = explode (",", $files);
 return $str_arr[0]; // returns value as [" value...."
 return $str_arr[1]; // returns value as " value...."]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this explode? And what _is_ in the `$request->images`?

Comment: $request->images contains array of base64 images. I am using explde to seperate these strings using "," because I am unable to iterate over the images array directly

Comment: `explode()` is used for splitting a _string_ to array of strings. If your `$request->images` is already an array then you don't need to explode it.

Comment: Are you sure `$request->images` is not a JSON string?